# .ui-page background image jQuery Mobile 1.4.3

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I have setup full page background image of my index page. (PS: I have multiple pages in one index.html - index page, about page, services page ,etc.) I want this image to be shown on index page only. The rest of the pages should have white background.

This is my css code:

```
.ui-page, #index .ui-content{
background: url(../images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

The problem I have is on other pages if the content is short, background image from .ui-page is visible. How do I assign .ui-page to index.html page only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the page id of the page that should have the background to the CSS rule:

```
 #page1.ui-page{
    background: url(http://lorempixel.com/1800/1800/abstract/2/) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/6xCc9/)**

In the demo page1 has the background and page2 does not.

Comment: For some reason its not working with pages that have a panel.

Comment: @SvenB, With a panel jQM adds a div with class ui-panel-wrapper. Set its background transparent:  http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/6xCc9/7/